# How can I apply a raster style to multiple layers using MapServer?

Tags: raster, wms, mapserver

I'm using [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/index.html) to display a raster in browser using a WMS request from OpenLayers. At the moment I have just one raster, and used the following method of styling it:

```
MAP      
    ###########
    NAME         "ny_pop"                                                                             
    UNITS         meters    
    SIZE          256 256
    STATUS        OFF
    DEBUG         ON
    IMAGECOLOR    128 128 255
    CONFIG        "MS_ERRORFILE" "ms.log"

    ###########    
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:900913"
    END

    ###########
    OUTPUTFORMAT
      NAME "png"
      DRIVER AGG/PNG
      MIMETYPE "image/png"
      IMAGEMODE RGB
      EXTENSION "png"
      FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=0.75"
    END

    ###########    
    WEB             
        METADATA
            "wms_title"           "WMS population layer"
            "wms_onlineresource"  "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=population.map&"            
            "wms_enable_request"  "GetMap GetFeatureInfo GetCapabilities"
        END
    END

    ###########    
    LAYER
        NAME      "new_york_pop"
        DATA      /home/mysite/webapps/htdocs/data/ny_pop_den.tif
        STATUS    OFF
        TYPE      RASTER   
        METADATA
            "wms_title"  "WMS NY Raster"
            "wms_srs"    "EPSG:900913"
        END

        CLASSITEM "[pixel]"

        # class using simple string comparison, equivelent to ([pixel] = 0)
        CLASS
            EXPRESSION "0"
            STYLE
              COLOR 0 0 0
            END
        END

          # class using an EXPRESSION using only [pixel].
        CLASS
            EXPRESSION ([pixel] > 0 AND [pixel] < 5000)
            STYLE
              COLOR 215 25 28
            END
        END

        CLASS
            EXPRESSION ([pixel] >= 5000 AND [pixel] < 10000)
            STYLE
              COLOR 253 174 97
            END 
    END

END
```

I want to include several more rasters layers in this mapfile. Is there a way that I can apply the style to multiple layers by creating a style object and applying it to each layer? I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology as I could not spot how to do this on the mapserver site.

I thought about generating this using php, or copy/pasting this layer structure. If I go the copy/paste route the mapfile would become extremely long and hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet.. Here's what we're left with...eg: the copy and paste method. Example:

```
LAYER                                                   #-> BEGIN LAYER DEFINITION: Land Cover <-#
    NAME    landcover                                   # Layer identifier
    DATA    "data/wgs84/landcover_360.tif"              # Name of the data (in this case, string identifying a raster)
    STATUS  DEFAULT                                     # Default (always on) <-OR-> ON/OFF (passed into query string)
    TYPE    RASTER                                      # Data type (point, line, polygon or raster)
    OPACITY 100                                         # Layer transparency (0-100 <-OR-> ALPHA)
    OFFSITE 0 0 0                                       # Image background colour

    CLASS                                               #-> BEGIN CLASS
        NAME    "Land Cover: Urban"                     # Name of class (used in legend)
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 2)                        # Attribute query

        STYLE                                           #-> BEGIN STYLE
            OPACITY 100                                 # Transparency
            COLOR 0 0 0                                 # Fill colour
        END                                             #-> END STYLE
    END                                                 #-> END CLASS

    CLASS                                               #-> BEGIN CLASS
        NAME    "Land Cover: Agriculture"               # Name of class (used in legend)
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 1)                        # Attribute query

        STYLE                                           #-> BEGIN STYLE
            OPACITY 80                                  # Transparency
            COLOR 0 0 0                                 # Fill colour
        END                                             #-> END STYLE
    END                                                 #-> END CLASS
END                                                     #-> END LAYER DEFINITION: Land Cover <-#

LAYER                                                   #-> BEGIN LAYER DEFINITION: Roads <-#
    NAME    roads                                       # Layer identifier
    DATA    "data/wgs84/roads_360.tif"                  # Name of the data (in this case, string identifying a raster)
    STATUS  DEFAULT                                     # Default (always on) <-OR-> ON/OFF (passed into query string)
    TYPE    RASTER                                      # Data type (point, line, polygon or raster)
    OPACITY 100                                         # Layer transparency (0-100 <-OR-> ALPHA)
    OFFSITE 0 0 0                                       # Image background colour

    CLASS                                               #-> BEGIN CLASS
        NAME    "Roads: Within 2km"                     # Name of class (used in legend)
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 2)                        # Attribute query

        STYLE                                           #-> BEGIN STYLE
            OPACITY 100                                 # Transparency
            COLOR 0 0 0                                 # Fill colour
        END                                             #-> END STYLE
    END                                                 #-> END CLASS

    CLASS                                               #-> BEGIN CLASS
        NAME    "Roads: Between 2 and 15km"             # Name of class (used in legend)
        EXPRESSION ([pixel] = 1)                        # Attribute query

        STYLE                                           #-> BEGIN STYLE
            OPACITY 50                                  # Transparency
            COLOR 0 0 0                                 # Fill colour
        END                                             #-> END STYLE
    END                                                 #-> END CLASS
END                                                     #-> END LAYER DEFINITION: Roads <-#
```

> [Style](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/style.html#style) holds parameters for symbolization and styling. Multiple
>   styles may be applied within a CLASS or LABEL.
>
> This object appeared in 4.0 and the intention is to separate logic
>   from looks. The final intent is to have named styles (Not yet
>   supported) that will be re-usable through the mapfile. This is the way
>   of defining the appearance of an object (a CLASS or a LABEL).

Comment: wow - thanks! It's great to see examples of clear mapfiles. I'm going to update my commenting after reading your clear example. I think I'll probably try and generate the file in python to make it easier to handle.

Comment: Cheers! I am a nut for clear and well commented code so by all means, copy me! ;)